# Unable to get any analysis result on Sonarqube server after running analysis using Sonar scanner for msbuild

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-msbuild-runner, sonarscanner

I am using sonarqube commercial as my solution contains vb code too and im running  analysis with sonar scanner for msbuild. I am using scanner as per given [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) . I can see the project on server url but result is zero for all parameters.
I have downloaded sonar scanner for msbuild from first link given [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild)
I have removed project-properties file from solution folder since it was asking for the same.Its showing 'Calculating CPD for 0 Files','Zero file indexed' .What could be the error ? Where am i going wrong? I am running scanner in the root folder.[image: 1] [image: 2]  [image: 3]  [image: 4]

Comment: Did you install the [SonarVB](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarVB) plugin? This is a commercial product....

Comment: It looks like the scanner targets are being included in the build phase, but Roslyn analysis is not being executed. Are there any warnings in the build? Which version of MSBuild are you using? Also, check that Quality Profile used by the project contains active VB rules.